# Rxjs conditional delay

Tags: rxjs5

I want an observable to be delayed depending on its value. For example:

```
of(someBool).pipe(delay(1000))
```

skip delay when `someBool` is false, but wait a sec when it's true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `delayWhen` for that:

```
of(someBool).pipe(
  delayWhen(val => val ? interval(1000) : of(undefined))
)
```

---

Side note, according to the docs using `empty()` instead of `of()` should IMHO work, but doesn't appear to. I believe this might be a bug. I have [reported it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3663).

Comment: It works when `of` takes zero as parameter, but it didn't let me edit.

Comment: That's just the typing. I added an explicit `undefined` as an argument.

Comment: for me this is not working when of takes no parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Example. Suppose you are implementing a login page and you want to wait until you get some token to put it in another Observable or Cookies. Then you can wait a value of your Observable (`someBool` here I used `this.authService.isLoggedIn`). So you can do something like this:

```js
return this.authService.isLoggedIn
  .pipe(
    delayWhen(loggedIn => loggedIn ? interval(0) : interval(10000)),
  );
```

And when a state of `isLoggedIn` is changed a user will be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** In future versions, empty notifiers will no longer re-emit the source value on the output observable.

```
someBool$.pipe(
  delayWhen(val => val ? timer(1000) : timer(0))
)
```